# Char and String manipulation in Java

Tags: java, string

A simple question that I don't know if Java has also a simple solution.

I have a string like: `name.ext.ext.out.end`

I need to get rid of `.out`, always the penultimate extension. Is there a kind of `indexof()`, but beginning from the end? I know how to do this in a rudimentary way, but maybe there are much better ones.

Comment: Have you tried searching google for "java string 6 api"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [`lastIndexOf(..)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int,%20int%29) which should do.

Comment: I hadn't seen it in String documentation! sorry. The downvote was not me

Answer (score 3):

If you know that is will always be ".out" why not use the `replace()` method in the String class API.

```
String extension = ".out";
String name = "name.ext.ext.out.end";
String newName = name.replace(extension, "");
```

EDIT: Different Solution

```
String extension = ".out";
String name = "name.ext.ext.out.end";

//searches backward from the end of the string
name.lastIndexOf(extension, name.length());
```

Comment: this will replace all `.out`s. For a file named `out.jpg.png.out.end` it will fail. I was under the impression that he wants the get rid of the last one only.

Comment: No, I wrote .out just as an example, it can be another value. @Bozho gave me the solution

Comment: ahh I see. Then lastIndexOf() would probably be the way to go. Ill edit my post

Comment: Actually, nowhere in his question did he indicate that he only wants to get rid of the last ".out".

Comment: "always the penultimate extension"

Answer (score 2):

Get the index using `lastIndexOf()`

You could do `replace()` with specified string to be replaced by ""

Answer (score 0):

You question is pretty simple: how to remove the *penultimate*. This is pretty simple but you have to do it in two passes... Here it is:

```
    /**
     * Returns the penultimate of a string.
     */
public static String getPenultimate( String str, char separator ){
    int pos1 = str.lastIndexOf(separator);
    if( pos1 > 0 ){
        String substr = str.substring(0, pos1 );
        int pos2 = substr.lastIndexOf(separator);
        if( pos2 > 0 ){
            return substr.substring(0, pos2) + str.substring(pos1);
        }
        return str.substring(pos1+1);
    }
    return null;
}

public static void main( String[] args){
    System.out.println( getPenultimate( "name.ext.v2.out.end", '.' ) );
    System.out.println( getPenultimate( "out.end", '.' ) );
    System.out.println( getPenultimate( "end", '.' ) );
}
```

The *main()* gives the following results:

```
    name.ext.v2.end
    end
    null
```

*null* is returned when data is insufficient. *separator* is the dot to pass as parameter (the method is generic).